# Why is it ambiguous between an int object and a function type?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is the code example:

```
namespace A
{
  int k;
}
void k(int,int){/*dosomething*/}
int main()
{
  using namespace A;
  k(1,1);//ooop!k is ambiguous!
}
```

What happened? I thought it should not be ambiguous since they are different types. Why is it ambiguous?  With `int k` it is not possible to do `k(1,1)`.

So it has nothing to do with what the name actually is?Even if a name that is not a function type will also cause ambiguity when we use `k(1,1)` ,which is wrong in grammar because `int k` is not function?

Comment: To which namespace does `k(int,int)` belong? Which namespace is specified for the block where `k(1,1)` is used? Does `namespace A` have a `k (int, int)`? Does it have a `int k`?

Comment: The quote from cppref does not apply, as you don't declare any names inside `main`.

Comment: @BoPersson the top-voted answer says "there are two names found in the same scope", so I quoted this to prove "there are no two names in the sams scope".Two names are found,but they are not in the same scope.

Comment: @bigxiao - The quote says "being declared", but nothing is being declared in main. You can declare a new `k` inside main, and that will hide the other two. That's what the quote is referring to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lookup of the name `k` is ambiguous because there are two matching declarations visible, `::k` and `::A::k` .

The exact rule can be found in the C++ Standard (N4659 [basic.lookup]/1):

> Name lookup associates the use of a name with a set of declarations of that name. The declarations found by name lookup shall either all declare the same entity or shall all declare functions; in the latter case, the declarations are said to form a set of overloaded functions.

---

Looking up an unqualified name that is used for a function call has two stages:

1. Unqualified lookup of the name
2. Argument-dependent lookup of the name.

**The unqualified name lookup rules, even when looking up a name that is being used for a function call, find any declaration of that name.**  (The rule is NOT that it only searches for function declarations of that name).  This stage finds both `::k` and `::A::k` regardless of whether those are functions, `int`s, or whatever.

The argument-dependent lookup does have a rule that only function declarations are found for that part of the lookup. But that is not relevant to this code.

---

The relevant behaviour of the `using` directive is covered by [basic.lookup.unqual]/2 (edited by me to just show the parts relevant to this question):

> For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules, the declarations from the namespace nominated by the using-directive are considered members of that enclosing namespace.

This clarifies that `using namespace A;` does not actually introduce the members of `A` into the scope of `main()`; but it means that when looking up a name in the global namespace (because that is the innermost enclosing namespace of the site of the using declaration), the names from `A` will also be found there.

Comment: But wait!As far as I know,the **using directive** does not introduce name in the scope!

Comment: @bigxiao Why wouldn't it.  That's its purpose.

Comment: @bigxiao It doesn't stop you from declaring the same named variable, but you're not doing that, you're using a name

Comment: @NathanOliver I think " two names found in the same scope" is not true.Two names are found,but they are not in the same scope.

Comment: @bigxiao I edited my answer to address that. By "scope" I meant the scope where the lookup occurs, it can see two different `k`.  I didn't mean to imply that the `k` were actually declared in that scope.

Comment: @M.M So it has nothing to do with what the name actually is?Even if a name that is not a function type will also cause ambiguity when we use `k(1,1)` ,which is wrong in grammar?

Comment: @bigxiao you should get the same error if you change `void k(int, int);` to `int k;`

Comment: @bigxiao When the using directive is being used, don't think of the variable k and the function k as being declared in the same scope. They were already previously declared in their own scope. the variable k is in ::A::k and the function void k(int,int) is in ::k(int,int). In the main function when you apply `using namespace A;` what happens here it takes every symbol after `A::` and it kind of shifts it as if it were in the global `::` scope for visibility. Now the compiler has to make a choice on the available symbols and sees I have a k and a k. Did you mean int k() or void k(int,int)...

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to resolve the ambiguity:

1st:

```
int main() {
    A::k = 5;
    ::k( 1, 1 );
}
```

2nd:

```
int main() {
    using namespace A;
    A::k = 5;   
    ::k(1, 1);
}
```

3rd:

```
namespace A {
   int k;
}

namespace B {
   void k( int, int ) { /* do something */ }
}

int main() {
   using namespace A or B but not both!
   if A then k = 5; okay && k(1,1); error
   if B then k(1, 1); okay && k = 5; error
   if both again ambiguous unless A::k = 5; || B::k(1,1);
   return 0;
}
```

Due to the nature of ambiguity it doesn't truly pay to use `using namespace A`. And this is why it is considered bad practice to have `using namespace std;` either in the global scope or directly in the main function. It is okay to use it in a function or a member function of a class/struct as long as you don't conflict with any other library.

I ran this in my IDE visual studio 2017 CE and here is the compiler error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ChemLab, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>main.cpp
1>c:\...\visual studio 2017\projects\chemlab\chemlab\main.cpp(17): error C2872: 'k': ambiguous symbol
1>c:\...\visual studio 2017\projects\chemlab\chemlab\main.cpp(8): note: could be 'void k(int,int)'
1>c:\...\visual studio 2017\projects\chemlab\chemlab\main.cpp(6): note: or       'int A::k'
1>Done building project "ChemLab.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When you use the `using namespace directive` it will take everything that is in that namespace and make it visible to main. So now in main you have both the `namespace A` and the `global namespace` visible within main. Since you have both visible you now have 2 identifiers or symbols in the look up table named `k`. And when you call `k(1, 1)` it doesn't know which one you intended to choose.

This is no different than doing this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <string>

class string {
public:
    char* _chars;
};

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    string myString; // error ambiguous did you mean ::string or std::string?

    return 0;
}
```

This might provide you with some more insight:

When the `using directive` is being used, don't think of the `variable k` and the `function k` as being `declared` in the `same scope`. They were previously declared in their own scope. The variable `k` is in `::A::k` and the function `void k(int,int){}` is in `::k(int,int){}`. In the main function when you apply the `using namespace A;` what happens here it takes `every symbol` `after` `A::` and it kind of shifts it as if it were in the `global` `::` `scope` for visibility. Now the compiler has to make a choice on the available symbols and sees I have a `k` and a `k`. Did you mean `int k(){}` or `void k(int,int){}`...

Comment: But why is here ambiguous? Because for `int k`,it;s not possible to do `k(1,1)` .

Comment: @bigxiao you have 2 identifiers named `k`.

Comment: Your exmaple is understandable for me,because both `string` are all class,so here is a collision.But `int k` is not a function.

Comment: @bigxiao It doesn't matter that its a function, enum, class etc. It is an identifier or a symbol that is generated in a look up table of the namespace's block or scope.

Answer (score -2):

The ambiguity comes from the name. There is no way to overload a variable like you would a function/method, so there is a "clash" in the names.

In order to get the "k" that you want, you need to specify the namespace.

```
namespace A
{ 
    int k;
}

void k(int, int) {/*dosomething*/ }

int main()
{
    using namespace A;
    ::k(1, 1); // uses the global namespace
    A::k = 5; // uses the namespace A
 }
```

Or, to take the namespace out of the equation:

```
void k(int, int) {/*dosomething*/ }
void k(int, int, float) {}

int main()
{
    int k;

    // all of these are now ambiguous
    k(1, 1);
    k(1, 2, 0.4);
    k = 5;
}
```

Comment: In your second example it is not ambiguous; the name lookup in `main` finds the `k` declared in `main` and stops looking.

Comment: True. I got ahead of myself in assuming the error was ambiguity. It was instead error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 (or 3) arguments